# FillPDF Generating PDFs of 0 bytes when using local PDFtk

Tags: 7, files

We just moved from Scientific Linux to Ubuntu, and as a result have moved from FillPDF Local Server to locally installed PDFtk.

All PDFs that are generated are now 0 bytes. There are no related errors showing up in the Drupal logs, and in fact I see a notice from the [FillPDF](https://www.drupal.org/project/fillpdf) module that

> the PDF was created (User generated form "nbca_archival_reproduction_agreement.pdf" for node "NBCA Reproduction Form".).

I'm also not seeing any errors in the server logs either.

Has anyone else encountered this problem? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Pablo

Comment: Does your PDFtk work when you use it locally independently? Not through Drupal. What version? https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/modules/fillpdf/installation#pdftk The issue on the project is the best place for this as you've correctly concluded ;) (https://www.drupal.org/project/fillpdf/issues/3033428)

Comment: Hi Prkos. Thx for the reply.

The version of pdftk is 2.02.

I took the original PDF that is being manipulated and ran the following command from their help page:


`pdftk nbca_archival_reproduction_agreement.pdf cat 2-3 output out1.pdf`

The resulting out1.pdf was correct, with the first page removed.

Any ideas or thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Pablo

Comment: Also the FillPDF module version is 7.x-1.15.